# What all a beginner in iphone app development should be aware about?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am a Beginner in iPhone Development, i have worked with .net web and window applications and only used c# language.

i am planning to make simple application for iPhone.  After a long searching, i came to know that xcode kit is used in development and objective c is the language used.

i am confused with many questions..please help me

These are some basic things i need to know in a beginner point of view.

- What all development tools should be used?
- Should i need a mac OS system to develop iPhone apps or can i use windows xp OS?
- Should i need to register as iOS developer($99 a year)?
- How can i test the developed app, should i need a iPhone or is there any simulator?
- Is Objective c similar to c# or c++ ?
- Can i develop iPhone apps in .net?
- What all should i know before starting to develop an app?
- Which all database can be used in iPhone apps development

Please help with your valuable answers regarding all the basics to learn iPhone development

Answer (score 6):

**1) What all development tools should be used?**

Well you need to install xcode and iOS SDK. To get them you have download it from apple's [developer](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) website (size in GB's). To run xcode  you need a MAC. You need
devices to test your app.

**2) Should i need a mac OS system to develop iPhone apps or can i use windows xp OS?**

You need mac. Search "iphone development on windows" on this site itself.You will get a lot of info.

**3) Should i need to register as iOS developer($99 a year)?**

Without registering you can

1. download sdk
2. start developement using simulator

   You can't run on device or upload app to app store without registering.

**4) How can i test the developed app, should i need a iPhone or is there any simulator?**

Simulator is there. But never upload an app only tested in simulator. You must test on device.

**5) Is Objective c similar to c# or c++ ?**

I came from C/C++ background and I found objective C easy. You will take 2 to 3 days to fully understand objective C method syntax, property and synthesize,
class and object methods. The most difficult thing to learn for me was memory management. **Remember there is no garbage collection in iphone**, you will have to
do all memory management yourself.

EDIT: There is a change in iOS 5.0. We still don't have garbage collection. But Now we have Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), which add memory management code at compile time. We don't have to do release/autorelease code, but compiler will do it for you..

**6) Can i develop iPhone apps in .net?**

No, you can't.

**7) What all should i know before starting to develop an app?**

1. Basic programming concepts (OOP
   concept, language you will learn
   gradually)
2. Knowledge that you are working on an
   embedded device (I know iphone is
   powerful, but still it is an
   embedded device, not a desktop).
   Always make sure you use just enough
   memory and processor for your need.

Happy coding..

Comment: How can i download Xcode SDK, without registering? can u please give the link.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to the circle of iOS developers =)

To your questions:

**What all development tools should be used?**

Xcode provides you all you need. The IDE, the Build environment and loads of tools to analyze your code.

**Should i need a mac OS system to develop iPhone apps or can i use windows xp OS?**

I've heard there are also cross platform IDEs available, but I recommend to use Xcode. Xcode runs on Mac OS X – and Apple says, it only runs on Intel architecture. I've heard from some people, they managed to use Xcode on Power PC systems. In the end you will have problems to build your app on that architecture.

**Should i need to register as iOS developer($99 a year)?**

No need for that, if you don't want to publish your app to the app store OR test on a device. But there is also a simulator for different devices shipped with Xcode.

**How can i test the developed app, should i need a iPhone or is there any simulator?**

You don't need a device, but it's strongly recommended to get one. Since the simulator mentionded above uses your complete system ressources of your hosting Mac, you may take memory management too easy and explore bad surprises on a device.

**Is Objective c similar to c# or c++ ?**

It's not wrong to have experience with C and/or C++, the main concepts are the same. But you will see a whole new syntax which might be a little bit confusing for the first time. After you are familiar with it, you will appreciate the "speaking" method markup.

**What all should i know before starting to develop an app?**

You've already found stackoverflow.com for Questions and Gotchas. I recommend to get some books. Aaron Hillegass has written some nice Cocoa books. But maybe someone else can give you better recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to publish an app to the  app store you....

1-2) DO need a MAC with XCode installed

3) if you  want to publish the app on the store, yes

4) XCode + iOS SDK came with an iPhone/iPad simulator, wich works pretty well

(after obtaining a 99$ licence you can also activate some iphones to debug your app directly on the device
5) I mostly wrote app in web tecnology (have a look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) for this) so, i cannot answer you, sry

6) If you want to create an app wich have to basically display content taken from the web
  you should really consider the PhoneGap way. If you want to program something like a 3D game with hi-res animation or stuff like that you'll probably need to wrote a native (obj C-cocoa) app

Hope this helped :D

Answer (score 1):

```
What all development tools should be used?
    xcode mostly

Should i need a mac OS system to develop iPhone apps or can i use windows xp OS?
    Yes        

 Should i need to register as iOS developer($99 a year)?
   if you want to put up your apps on the appStore, then yes.

How can i test the developed app, should i need a iPhone or is there any simulator?
   There is a simulator with the xcode IDE. if you want to test it on an actual device, you'll have to pay the 99$ a year

Is Objective c similar to c# or c++ ?
   its a strict superset of C.

* Can i develop iPhone apps in .net?
  not that i know of.
```

you can develop Phone apps in JavaScript using http://www.appcelerator.com/
    What all should i know before starting to develop an app?

Answer (score 1):

> What all development tools should be used?

Apple Developer Tools, that you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).

> Should i need a mac OS system to develop iPhone apps or can i use windows xp OS?

Definitely you need a MacOS system.

> Should i need to register as iOS developer($99 a year)?

This is required in order to be able to run your app on a physical device for testing and for submitting you app to the App Store.

> How can i test the developed app, should i need a iPhone or is there any simulator?

Developer Tools include an iPhone/iPad simulator. You can also run the app on a physical device.

> Is Objective c similar to c# or c++ ?

Objective C is standard C with OO extensions resembling of Smalltalk.

> What all should i know before starting to develop an app?

The basic things is that you will learn bit by bit all you need to know.

I would start from reading an Objective C tutorial, to have a grasp of the language.
Then you could access some of the video material that is available online. Check [this](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/) and also get a look at the many introductory books available out there.